# how to call this datepicker function while each row of table data is having the same class='datapicker'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a table where I have the javascript function for datepicker and in that, table is also having add and delete row functionality.So, when ever a new row is created it will have the same id as the previous row .So, how to call the below function for each row of table.But constraint is that the table data will have same id ,name and class.This function is only working for first row and for the second it's not working .

Comment: Can you provide an example of the table? I am afraid it is not well designed.

Comment: Will need your HTML code. Also "id" attribute should be unique for all the elements. Having duplicate id's contradicts the purpose of identification attribute.

Comment: `it will having the same id as the previous row` so you gave the answer here. As the function is only working for the first row, I assume the duplicate ID's are the issue here.

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML? In this case you could assign unique IDs (that's how it should be anyway). Otherwise you could assign an attribute that you use like an id for each row. What do you think?

Comment: Call your datepicker function on every row addition. (on click on add button)

Comment: If you could paste your code to jsFiddle we could help then.

Comment: How are you generating this table of data?  Where does it come from?  Is there a value that is unique in each row?

Answer (score 0):

By WWW standards, no two objects in a dom should have same id. So may be you can edit the javascript code that adds/delete rows to have an iterant appended to the id. Meanwhile you could also use data-* attributes. [Read more about data-* attribs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). Writing this as an answer as its difficult to give you links in comment.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is, call datepicker after adding the new row also.

```
$tr.after($clone);
$("input.add").live('click', function() {        
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();

    // blah blah

    $tr.after($clone);
    $clone.find('input).datepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             showOn: 'button',
             buttonImage: 'jquery/images/calendar.gif',
             buttonImageOnly: true
           });
});
```

Also - a word of caution: Use `on` instead of `live`. live is deprecated in newer versions of jquery.

Comment: You add once on page load to apply on all the existing rows. Then you add individually to the roe being added (in the 'Add' click event). So all the rows have datepicker added to input. See, I also edited the answer. Need to be called on the input not on the entire row.